# Find $C^1$ class function such that

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Given:
$$g: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, g(x,y,z)=z^3-3xyz-x-8$$
Decide whether in the neighbourhood of the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$ there exist $C^1$ class function $z=z(x,y)$, such that $g(x,y,z(x,y))=0$. If there exists such a function then calculate $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}(0,0)$.

I do not know what to do with that, i have no idea what to start with.

Comment: The [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) should help.

Comment: Can you get an equation for z?

Comment: If you mean the coordinates of z i think the point will be $(0,0,2)$

Comment: but the implict function theorem will help when it comes to derivatives but how does it help when it comes to C1 class function